# WARNING Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException - tomcat dbcp2

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jmx, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using apache-tomcat-6.0.35 and upgraded DB Pooling Jar to **commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar** and **commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar**
I made following changes in apache-tomcat-6.0.35/conf/context.xml file

```
<Resource auth="Container"
description="ebook DB Connection"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
name="jdbc/ebookDS"
username="username"
password="password"
factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = cluster-b3-10)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = eb11dc) ))"
maxTotal="100"
maxIdle="20"
maxWaitMillis="30000"
accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" />
```

I have noticed following warning and info messages in tomcat catalina.out file when I add factory="org.apache.commons.**dbcp2**.BasicDataSourceFactory" in context.xml

```
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory]
Oct 28, 2015 10:48:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOTRENAME
Oct 28, 2015 10:48:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory]
Oct 28, 2015 10:48:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory hudson
Oct 28, 2015 10:48:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory]
 Oct 28, 2015 10:48:39 AM hudson.WebAppMain contextInitialized
 INFO: Home directory: /export/home/apps/ebookplus/.hudson
Oct 28, 2015 10:48:39 AM hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter init
INFO: CharacterEncodingFilter initialized. DISABLE_FILTER: false FORCE_ENCODING: false
Oct 28, 2015 10:48:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Oct 28, 2015 10:48:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory]
```

Any information about what is going on here would be greatly appreciated.